Emms doesn't play directory tree in OSX
I'm trying to use emms in emacs 29.4 for MacOSX Monterrey. Everything works fine except for playing files in nested folders. Here is my config:
;; MEDIA
;; EMMS
(emms-all)
(emms-default-players)
(emms-mode-line 1)
(emms-playing-time 1)
;; Source my music from my server:
(setq emms-source-file-default-directory "/Volumes/Coronila/Music"
      emms-playlist-buffer-name "*Music*"
      emms-info-asynchronously t
      emms-source-file-directory-tree-function 'emms-source-file-directory-tree-find)

And here is the error message after execute emms-play-directory-tree and put the the directory tree:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "No first track")
  signal(error ("No first track"))
  error("No first track")
  emms-playlist-first()
  emms-playlist-select-first()
  emms-playlist-current-select-first()
  emms-source-play(emms-source-directory "/Volumes/Coronila/Music")
  emms-play-directory("/Volumes/Coronila/Music")
  funcall-interactively(emms-play-directory "/Volumes/Coronila/Music")
  call-interactively(emms-play-directory record nil)
  command-execute(emms-play-directory record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "emms-play-directory" "emms-play-direc")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "emms-play-directory" "emms-play-direc")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)

I've tried different ways to reproduce the directory tree without success. Any help or recommendation is welcome.
UPDATED: I am sorry I forgot to mention that I tried play my music tree using emms-play-directory and put the path of my music folder obtaining the above error:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "No first track")
  signal(error ("No first track"))
  error("No first track")
  emms-playlist-first()
  emms-playlist-select-first()
  emms-playlist-current-select-first()
  emms-source-play(emms-source-directory "/Volumes/Coronila/Music")
  emms-play-directory("/Volumes/Coronila/Music")
  funcall-interactively(emms-play-directory "/Volumes/Coronila/Music")
  call-interactively(emms-play-directory record nil)
  command-execute(emms-play-directory record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "emms-play-directory" "emms-play-direc")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "emms-play-directory" "emms-play-direc")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)

And I also tried using emms-play-directory-tree and put the path of music folder obtaining a similar error:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "No first track")
  signal(error ("No first track"))
  error("No first track")
  emms-playlist-first()
  emms-playlist-select-first()
  emms-playlist-current-select-first()
  emms-source-play(emms-source-directory-tree "/Volumes/Coronila/Music/")
  emms-play-directory-tree("/Volumes/Coronila/Music/")
  funcall-interactively(emms-play-directory-tree "/Volumes/Coronila/Music/")
  call-interactively(emms-play-directory-tree record nil)
  command-execute(emms-play-directory-tree record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "emms-play-directory-tree" "emms-play-directory-tr")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "emms-play-directory-tree" "emms-play-directory-tr")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)

My bad, I'm sorry for the confusion.

What does your *Music* buffer look like? I suspect it is empty. You probably want emms-play-directory-tree? See Basic Commands in the manual.

Yes. I run run emms-play-directory-tree and put the path to folder with my music file but the the above error appears.

Your backtrace shows that you are running emms-play-directory, not emms-play-directory-tree. emms-play-directory will only look in the specified directory, not in any subdirectories. emms-play-directory-tree will look in subdirectories as well. IIUC of course...

I tried both emms-play-directory and emms-play-directory-treeobtaining similar error. I updated the question, I am sorry for the poor clarity in my question.

Try evaluating the following form: (emms-source-file-directory-tree "/Volumes/Coronila/Music/ (emms-source-file-regex)). Just copy it into your *scratch* buffer and press C-j after the closing paren. Does it give you a list of files? Or is it empty? What does /Volumes/Coronila/Music contain? And just to make sure: I asked you if your *Music* buffer is empty  - I assume so, but you have not confirmed that assumption. Please do.

There is a list like:
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (scan-error "Unbalanced parentheses" 84 1)
scan-sexps(86 -1)
forward-sexp(-1)
elisp--preceding-sexp()
elisp--eval-last-sexp(t)
eval-last-sexp(t)
eval-print-last-sexp(nil)
funcall-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil)
call-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil nil)
command-execute(eval-print-last-sexp)
And yes, Music buffer is empty

I had a typo in the form above. Please try this: (emms-source-file-directory-tree "/Volumes/Coronila/Music/" (emms-source-file-regex)).

It gives a text: "nil".

So the file scanner did not find any files that satisfy its criteria in the directory. Are you sure you have music files in there? Is this Linux or some other system? If Linux, you should be able to run the command find -L /Volumes/Coronila/Music/ -type f -iregex ".*\(mp3\)" from a terminal, to see if it can find any mp3 files (for example - the actual regex that is used is much more complicated and matches a lot of different music formats: mp3, wav, ogg, flac,  etc. etc.). Depending on what kind of music files you have, you might want to try another extension.

Thanks. Yes, I'm sure there are music files in the folder. Actually, emms-play-file works fine. It is MacOSX Monterrey 12.6.8.

If you invoke find --version  from the command line, what does it tell you?

The reason I'm asking is to see whether your external find program supports the capabilities required; in particular, does it support -L, -type, and -iregex? The first two should be no problem but the last one may be: it is part of GNU find but maybe not of the find program that you have available? If so, you might get things working by setting emms-source-file-directory-tree-function to 'emms-source-file-directory-tree-internal. Although the latter is slower than using the external find, it might work whether the external find might not.

[Comment converted to an answer.]
Your backtrace shows that you are running emms-play-directory, not emms-play-directory-tree. emms-play-directory will only look in the specified directory, not in any subdirectories. emms-play-directory-tree will look in subdirectories as well.
The doc string for emms-play-directory says:
An EMMS source for a whole directory tree - either DIR, or queried
from the user.

whereas the doc string for emms-play-directory-tree says:
An EMMS source for multiple directory trees - either DIR, or the
value of ‘emms-source-file-default-directory’.

I believe that both of these are misleading and should be reported as doc bugs.

The problem as touched by NickD is that any command that traverses a directory tree in emms requires the GNU version of the find command; specifically if emms-source-file-directory-tree-function is set to emms-source-file-directory-tree-find. OSX's default findcommand is other then the GNU version and neither is the GNU version preinstalled. You need to download the GNU version of find using brew install findutils and add the GNU find command to your path.
See more about installing GNU Version of find on mac here.
Once GNU is the default version of find, restart Emacs and  command related to directory trees should work again
